# Flickering issue on mouse over

Tags: jquery

I found many other members with the same problem except none of them where close enough to my script to fix the problem or I don't have the technical knowledge in jquery to solve it myself.

I have a simple slide up menu opposite of drop down and I noticed that it flickers when I mouse over the child li

I placed it here http://jsfiddle.net/noeg/F9QYb/2/ to demonstrate the issue

```
(function ($) {

$("#menu > ul > li:has(ul)").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();
});

})(this.jQuery);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a short delay:

```
$("#menu > ul > li:has(ul)").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).delay(300).slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).delay(300).slideUp();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/F9QYb/3/

Answer (score 0):

The white gap between the menu and the submenu is triggering `mouseleave` because it's not inside of the `<li>` anymore.

One way to solve this is to give padding on the menu items so that they meet the bottom of the submenu, therefore your cursor won't leave the `li` and it wont trigger `mouseleave`.

Here's a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/F9QYb/6/